# How to determine if a component is resolvable from an IHandlersFilter implementation

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to write a Castle Windsor v3 IHandlersFilter implementation that will filter out handlers that cannot be resolved.  This is in an effort to optionally restore the old (pre-castle 3) behavior of ResolveAll ([How to revert to old CollectionResolver behavior in Castle 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538603/how-to-revert-to-old-collectionresolver-behavior-in-castle-3))

My question is, from the SelectHandlers method, what is the best way (if any) to determine which of the input IHandlers are resolvable?  I have experimented with the IHandler.CanResolve method, but it takes parameters that are a bit more advanced than I typically deal with, so I'm not sure how to use the method properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `handler.CurrentState == HandlerState.Valid`

However be aware this is based on what Windsor can determine statically, therefore the answer may not always be 100% accurate (for example some components may have dynamic dependencies, so they will appear as unresolvable here, yet you'll be able to successfully resolve them when you try).

Comment: Thanks, Krzysztof.  Out of curiosity, is this the same reason that makes IOC-322 (http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-322) basically impossible to "fix"?

Comment: To a degree, yes, as well as the way creation of closed versions of open generic components works.